# Validate certificate chain in PKCS#7 format

Tags: openssl, x509, pkcs#7, asn.1

I've extracted PKCS#7 formatted in ASN1, and I'd like to verify it's certificate chain (meaning that each certificate was properly signed by the certificate above it from root to leaf).

In openssl, there's the following API :

```
int PKCS7_verify(PKCS7 *p7, 
                 STACK_OF(X509) *certs, 
                 X509_STORE *store, 
                 BIO *indata, 
                 BIO *out, 
                 int flags);
```

However, I don't have a trusted certificate store.

I have a separate function that validate the integrity of the root certificate and that's enough for me.

Assuming that I already trust the root certificate, why do I need the store certificates structure in order to verify that the chain is properly signed ?

thanks

Comment: Note `X509_cert_verify` which `PKCS7_verify` calls (unless you set `PKCS7_NOVERIFY` as Reinier noted) does fairly full chain validation which is much more than just verifying each cert's signature by its parent. It also checks expiration, several extensions if present especially BC and KU, and revocation if CRLs are provided (which is rare nowadays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is why do I need the store in order to verify that the chain is properly signed ?

You do not necessarily need a store parameter, you can set it to `NULL` as well and just verify the signature and not the entire chain of certificates. In that case, you should use the flag `PKCS7_NOVERIFY`, as explained in the [manual for `PKCS7_verify()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html). However, if you do want to verify the chain of certificates as well, you will somehow have to provide a mechanism to tell OpenSSL that you trust the root certificate and `X509_STORE` is a way to achieve that.

> However, I don't have a trusted certficate store.

From your question, it is not entirely clear what you situation is. But you do write that you have a separate function to "validate the integrity of the root certificate".

In that case, you can instantiate an `X509_STORE` object with [`X509_STORE_new()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_STORE_new.html) and add your trusted certificate to it. There is an example in the OpenSSL source code tree of that in the [setup_verify()](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1/apps/apps.c#L1223) function, which is for the case that the trusted certificate is available in a file. Or you could use [X509_STORE_add_cert()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/X509_STORE_add_cert.html) if that fits your purpose better. After you have added that trusted certificate, you can use the store as a parameter to your `PKCS7_verify()` invocation.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you precious help. Just to clarify, all i got is the PKCS#7 structure in asn1 format, extracted from PE file. First stage is verify the root certificate by hashing it and comparing the result to predefined whileList of certificate hashes. Then, I'd like to make sure that all the certificates in the chain were well signed by their upper level certificate (except for the root of course). So if add the root certificate to the X509_store, that would be enough for pkcs7_verify to verify the entire chain, right ?

Comment: In order to get the OpenSSL `PKCS7 *` structure from the ASN.1 format, you need to use [`d2i_PKCS7_bio()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/d2i_PKCS7_fp.html), but you may have done that already. But apart from that: yes, if you trust that root certificate, you can add it to the `X509_STORE` and that should be enough for `PKCS7_verify()` to verify the signature as well as the certificate chain up to your trusted certificate.

Comment: Thanks, you've confirmed my theory.

Comment: My pleasure. However, the best way to get confirmation is to create a set of tests :-)

Comment: Hi, after I've tried to validate my pkcs#7 in this method, I got the following error from ERR_print_error_fp : `140735569544136:error:21075075:lib(33):func(117):reason(117):pk7_smime.c:336:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate`
 any idea what it stands for ? thanks

Comment: That looks like OpenSSL is not able to build the entire certificate chain up to the/a trusted certificate. Maybe the [pkcs7 app](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/pkcs7.html) (for inspecting the chains) or the [smime app](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-smime.html) (for verifying) can help you analyze the situation?

Comment: Also, is your trusted certificate self-signed? If not, then check out the description of the `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` flag in the documentation on [`X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags.html)

Comment: Hi, I've tried using those tools, and successfully got the chain using `openssl pkcs7`. however, failed on the same reason during verification.. The problem is explained on a separated question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243943/understand-why-pkcs7-block-failed-during-verification-using-openssl. perhaps you can take a look ?

Comment: I have posted an answer to that question.