# Understand why pkcs7 block failed during verification using openssl

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, pkcs#7

I've got PKCS#7 Der formatted file called `p7` 
and an x509 certificate file called `mroot.der.cer` which matches the root certificate of p7 chain.

I'd like to verify my p7 certificate chain using openssl using the following commands :

```
First - convert my mroot trusted cert file to pem format. 
openssl x509 -in mroot.der.cer -inform der -outform PEM -out mroot.pem.cer

Second - verify the root chain using mroot.pem.cer
openssl  smime -verify -CAfile mroot.pem.cer -in p7 -inform DER -out blabla
```

However, I got the following error :

> Verification failure
>   140735569544136:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:343:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate

I also tried to add the last command, the  `-noverify` flag but got a different error.

> Verification failure
>   140735569544136:error:21071065:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_signatureVerify:digest failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_doit.c:1084:
>   140735569544136:error:21075069:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:signature failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:412:

The pkcs7 structure should be fine as I've extracted it from the PE file `iexlorer.exe` and from its chain I've extracted the root certificate, and refer to it as a trusted one.

What am I doing wrong here ?

P.s. 
To observe the same failures I did, I've uploaded the files to the following links :

https://ufile.io/vrqpt

https://ufile.io/ajgex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your uploaded example files have a few properties which prevent it from being verified.

First, the certificate of the signer in the `p7` file has expired on `Apr 24 22:33:39 2014 GMT`. You will have to disable checking of the expiration date if you want to verify the chain. This is programmatically done with the verify flag `X509_V_FLAG_NO_CHECK_TIME`, or the option `-no_check_time` for the OpenSSL `smime -verify` tool.

Then, your "root of trust", found in the `mroot.pem.cer` file is not the right one. You extracted the `Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA` certificate whereas the signer of the `p7` file chains up to the `Microsoft Code Signing PCA` certificate.

Let's say that you extract that correct certificate to a file called `trust.pem.cer`. That certificate is not self-signed: its issuer is the `Microsoft Root Certificate Authority`. You will have to indicate that you are using a so-called partial chain if you want such a certificate to be at the end of the chain.  This is programmatically done with the verify flag `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN`, or the option `-partial_chain` for the OpenSSL `smime -verify` tool.

Also, it looks like the OpenSSL implementation of the PKCS7 verification requires your certificate to include the extended key usage of S/MIME signing, which your certificate does not include. It looks like this can be worked around by setting a code-signing purpose for the OpenSSL `X509_STORE`. The OpenSSL `smime -verify` tool does not expose this kind of setting so you will have to do this programmatically by setting the `XKU_CODE_SIGN` purpose. `XKU` stands for eXtended Key Usage and, as a caveat, the OpenSSL documentation around that is virtually non-existent. You have to thoroughly test this if you decide to use it.

The piece of code below (return code checking omitted) successfully verifies the certificate chain in your `p7` file, but not the signature:

```
BIO *bio_p7 = BIO_new_file("p7", "r");
PKCS7 *p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(bio_p7, NULL);
X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
X509_LOOKUP *lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(store, X509_LOOKUP_file());
X509_LOOKUP_load_file(lookup, "trust.pem.cer", X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
X509_STORE_set_purpose(store, XKU_CODE_SIGN); /* see caveat above */
X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags(
    X509_STORE_get0_param(store),
    X509_V_FLAG_NO_CHECK_TIME | X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN);
int retcode = PKCS7_verify(p7, NULL, store, NULL, NULL, PKCS7_NOSIGS);
```

For a verification of the signature itself: the function [verify_pe_pkcs7() in `osslsigncode.c`](https://sourceforge.net/p/osslsigncode/osslsigncode/ci/master/tree/osslsigncode.c#l2063) gives example code to do that. Its `PKCS7_verify()` invocation does not verify the certificate chain, but it does check the signature. This requires extraction of a hash which is stored in a Microsoft-specific element in the p7 of a type called `SpcIndirectDataContent`, as pointed out by @dave_thompson_085 below. It is possible to verify the signature that was taken over that hash. For a complete verification, you will also need to re-calculate the hash over the PE file itself and compare it to the hash value found in the p7.

This answer is based on OpenSSL 1.1.1. Just now, I realize that you are using libressl, which is based on a (much) older version of OpenSSL. It might not work in your case. For example, for my version of libressl, the `smime -verify` tool does not support the `partial_chain` and `no_time_check` options because those were introduced in the OpenSSL 1.1.0 branch.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help again. The main misconception I had is that the root certificate reside inside the pkcs7 block of the PE file where in fact it I should get it somewhere else (like in windows root certificate list). Now, it's working, but I wonder if it's also possible that the root certificate will be part of the chain as the last one, and sign itself ?

Comment: For verification of a certificate chain to have any value, you have to end with a certificate that you (or the OS) somehow know and trust -- self-signed or not. By the way, looking at the chain that you uploaded, it has a field called "Authority Information Access" that points to the certificate of the root: http://www.microsoft.com/pki/certs/MicrosoftRootCert.crt .

Comment: Actually the Authenticode p7 signature is on data that _is_ embedded, but it has MS-defined structure SpcIndirectDataContent. OpenSSL doesn't handle the case where embedded data is not type pkcs7-data and not encoded as OCTET STRING, which is presumably why the code you point to makes its own memBIO to feed to PKCS7_verify. At commandline using `-content` to specify the value part of the contents does verify the signature (with `-noverify` to avoid the problems with verifying the cert chain, especially EKU).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for weighing in. My conclusion was also that the signature is on data that is embedded, but that that data is a hash of the *actual* PE contents. So to do a complete verification, that hash over the PE contents would have to be calculated for verification as well. Is that in line with your understanding?

Comment: Yes. But I took this Q to be only about the part of the process that involves the p7; doing or checking the file hash is a different problem (though also important).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I updated the section about verification of the signature to reflect your useful remark.